# How to fix data import to Windows EC2 from S3 bucket

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I got a Windows Server 2012 R2 EC2 instance and fail to import txt-files from a S3 bucket.

I want to set up a regular data import from an S3 bucket to the EC2 instance using the aws-cli. To test the command, I opened the command prompt with administration rights, navigated to the directory, where I want to import the files and run the following command.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybuckt/ . --recursive
```

Then I get an error like the following for every file in the bucket:

```
download failed: s3://mybuckt/filename.txt to .\filename.txt [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I end up with a list of empty files in my directory. The list is equal to that on the bucket but the text files are plain empty.

When I try the command without recursive, nothing happens. No error messages, no files copied.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybuckt/ .
```

Here are my questions:

1. Why is the recursive option wrong when I import the files?
2. What can I check in the configuration of the EC2 instance, to verify that it is correctly set up for the data import?

Comment: That error message is strange, but I would check that the IAM role you are using (probably assigning to the EC2 server) has actual read access for the S3 objects. Given the behavior it sounds like it might only have list object access.

Comment: "aws s3 cp s3://mybuckt/ ." would not copy anything as you need to either specify the object name or use --recursive. Have you tried to copy a single object and check if it throws the same error? I tried to regenerate various scenarios where like changing the bucket policies by giving List object access but failed to regenerate the error as GetObject policy gives List and download access. And if this was the access issue, it would give the error as "Access Denied". Can you also check the other CLI commands if they are working fine?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify any files to copy. You should use:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybuckt/* . --recursive
```

Or, you could use:

```
aws s3 sync s3://mybuckt/ . --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my specific problem here was that I had to specify the file name on the bucket as well as on my EC2 instance.

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybuckt/file.txt nameOnMyEC2.txt
```